# PHP/ImageMagick/Ghostcript: change output + input file paths

Tags: php, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have Ghostscript installed and ImageMagick (DLL).

The following PHP code works fine:

```
exec("convert test_pdf.pdf[0] $value.jpg");
```

But I want to read the PDF *input* from a different path (not from the location of PHP page).
I also want to write the *output* to a different path.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable for the different path and add it to your exec command:

```
<?php
    $path = "/path/to/file/";
    exec('convert '.$path.'test_pdf.pdf[0] '.$path.$value.'.jpg');
?>
```

You'll need to also make sure you have permissions set correctly for the new path in order to read/write from it using the exec command.